# NonNull problem in MainActivity.java flutter

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

my project was working properly in debug mood. when I Open MainActivity.java file this shows a problem on `import androidx.annotation.NonNull;`

and show the error below.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Abdullah Al Mamun\AndroidStudioProjects\product_sale\android\build.gradle' line: 32

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0] 
on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

In MainActivity.java file I have the problem I cant fixed it

[image: In MainActivity.java file I have the problem I cant fixed it]

problem is here

[image: problem is herer]

**build.gradle below**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to migrate to Android X, check [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration).